# EXFAT vs FAT32 speed for cpy -> exfat slower

Tags: performance, filesystems, busybox, fat32, exfat

As I'm working on an embedded system treating file management on media, I noticed that, using a same media (USB or SD, formated several times on both FAT32 and exfat fs), when I try to copy a file on it, it's faster in fat32 than in exfat (2 times faster).
I was wondering why I have such a difference.

I used basic busybox 1.24.1 cp function, or tar_append_tree function (from libtar), I have the same result. When I compare the cpy duration on my windows, I can't notice any difference. Do you have any clue to make me understand why there is such a gap between fat32 and exfat considering copy duration ?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: I've experienced similar results with formatting SD cards with fat32 vs exfat. Did you find an answer to this?